GraphiQL in ASP.NET Core 8.0
I have integrated GraphiSQL with ASP.NET Core 8.0.
Scenario 1
I have used GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL 7.7.2 with ASP.NET Core 8.0. I could see the tabs pretty, history, explorer
Scenario 2
I have used GraphQL.Server.Ui.GraphiQL 8.0.3 with ASP.NET Core 8.0. I could see the tabs pretty, history not explorer tab. So I am not able to select the properties
Here are two screenshot, one with GraphiQL 7 and another with GraphiQL 8:

How to show the explorer tab in newer versions of GraphiQL?
